# What will happen if I use RCBO where there is no neutral in the system?

Tags: circuit-protection, low-voltage, leakage-current, circuit-breaker, over-current

I need some help. Could you please go through the scenario and try to answer my query below?

> - This system is installed in a ship where there is no neutral connection available.
> - A 440V/220V step-down transformer is used to distribute the power to the feeder circuit.
> - The feeder circuit is protected with a 2 pole RCBO.

I would like to know how the RCBO will work in the above scenario,

Option-1 - RCBO will trip instantly when I power ON.

Option-2 - RCBO will work with over-current protection but no leakage current protection.

Comment: RCBO = Residual Current Breaker with Over-Current

Comment: Thanks for your response, Could you please more specific, Which option will be true.

Comment: I have no knowledge of ships or generators. But an expert will probably have more to say about it. Please wait for a response. In the meantime, if you have any schematics to share that would help immensely. It is not feasible or productive to talk about electrical systems without schematics.

Comment: There is no option here other than producing a simplified wiring diagram of what you are talking about. If you have intentionally omitted saying the system is three phase then that's very naughty.

Comment: I don't know anything about ship power systems, but neutral is the return path to the generator. There has to be a neutral or there's no power at all.

Comment: I'm guessing what @nid actually means is that the "neutral" is not at ground potential?

If so, I'd say the RCBO will work just fine. Ground potential in relation to the neutral/phase potential makes no difference for the RCBO. Only that the RCBO will not trip only due to a short between one of the phase/neutral to ground, as this will not create a leakage current.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know how the RCBO will work in the above scenario,
>
> Option-1 - RCBO will trip instantly when I power ON.
>
> Option-2 - RCBO will work with over-current protection but no leakage
> current protection.

The answer is Option-2.

An 'earth fault monitor' could be used to trigger an alarm in the case of a fault.

[image]

The fault could then be located and cleared.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on requirement and ultimately 'Auto-isolation' of supply. Imagine what can happen in case the control power gets knocked off due to a trip instance.
Very tricky but you can install toroid type devices for protection and the key is to keep Domestic Receptacles completely isolated with Control power distribution. Good luck with that